# Trying to create a TODO list and can't add the text to the list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a todo list
when the "New TODO" button is clicked, a text field and submit button appear on the screen.
But then when I press the submit button, the page looks like the initial start page. And everything disappears.
The function "newTODO()" creates the text box and submit button.
The function "subitTodo()" removes the text box and submit button, and adds the text from that text box to the "li" element.
Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')

function newTodo() {
  //alert('New TODO button clicked!')
  //create a text field and submit button
  var newTODO = document.createElement("LI")
  newTODO.id = 'newTODOListItem'
  list.appendChild(newTODO)

  var form = document.createElement("FORM")
  //form.innerHTML = "Enter a TODO"
  form.id = 'TODOList'
  newTODO.appendChild(form)

  var x = document.createElement("INPUT")
  x.type = 'text'
  x.id = 'newTODOText'
  x.name = 'name1'
  form.appendChild(x)

  var y = document.createElement("INPUT")
  y.type = 'submit'
  y.value = 'Submit'
  y.onClick = 'submitTodo(newTODO, form, x.value)'
  form.appendChild(y)
}

function submitTodo(newTODO, TODOList, taskText) {
  //after submit is clicked
  newTODO.removeChild(TODOList)
  var myP = document.createElement("P")

  newTODO.appendChild(myP)
  myP.innerHTML = taskText
}
```

Comment: A `submit` button, when clicked, submits the enclosing form. A `<form>` without an `action` attribute submits its content to "itself"/the same page. And that is what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

There has a lot of issues.

- The event is `onclick`, not `onClick`
- You made the button type `submit`, which is submitting the form
- You passed the handler function as a string

I fixed the issues here with the button type button. If you want to keep your button type submit, you must preventDefault on form submit.

```js
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')

function newTodo() {
  //alert('New TODO button clicked!')
  //create a text field and submit button
  var newTODO = document.createElement("LI")
  newTODO.id = 'newTODOListItem'
  list.appendChild(newTODO)

  var form = document.createElement("FORM")
  //form.innerHTML = "Enter a TODO"
  form.id = 'TODOList'
  newTODO.appendChild(form)

  var x = document.createElement("INPUT")
  x.type = 'text'
  x.id = 'newTODOText'
  x.name = 'name1'
  form.appendChild(x)

  function submitHandler() {
    submitTodo(newTODO, form, x.value)
  }

  var y = document.createElement("INPUT")
  y.type = 'button'
  y.value = 'Submit'
  y.onclick = submitHandler;
  form.appendChild(y)
}

function submitTodo(newTODO, TODOList, taskText) {
  //after submit is clicked
  newTODO.removeChild(TODOList)
  var myP = document.createElement("P")

  newTODO.appendChild(myP)
  myP.innerHTML = taskText
}
```

```html
<ul id="todo-list"></ul>
<p>
  Item count: <span id="item-count"></span> Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count"></span>
</p>
<button onclick="newTodo()">New todo</button>
```